# Can't call HttpResponse.StatusCode to set HTTP Status Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I have the following function:

```
private ViewResult HandleInvalid()
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    return View("Invalid");
}
```

On development machine (Windows 7), everything works well. The "Invalid" view is returned, along with status code 404.

On the production machine (Windows Server 2008), code execution stopped at the Response.StatusCode line and a status code 403 is returned along with empty content.

This happens on both ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC. Any idea what may cause this?

Comment: Are you sure that the controller action is ever hit on the production machine?

Comment: Absolutely. If I comment out the third line (the .StatusCode = 404), it works perfectly fine (but it returns 200 instead of 404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while but, what you can do is throw an HttpException(404, "Invalid")

Comment: Since I answered this a year ago, another alternative is to change the return type to ActionResult and return a HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "Invalid")